# Как / чем собрать несколько svg в один svg

Tags: css3, html5, svg

Имею вот такие 3 svg

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 33 18" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M16.6 0C16.5 0 16.4 0 16.3 0C8.50002 0 1.90002 5.5 0.400024 12.8C2.60002 14.1 6.20002 17.2 15 14.6C19.4 13.3 25 11.6 32.4 17.6C32.4 17.3 32.4 17 32.4 16.6C32.7 7.6 25.5 0.2 16.6 0ZM14.1 11.7C8.40003 13.4 5.40002 12.4 3.90002 11.5C5.90002 6.5 10.7 3 16.2 3H16.5C22.1 3.1 26.9 6.8 28.7 11.8C24 9.5 19.5 10 14.1 11.7Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 33 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M13.5 2.90002C8.9 4.30002 4.7 3.90002 0 0.900024C0 2.00002 0.1 3.60003 0.2 4.60003C2.6 6.50003 8.3 7.80002 14.4 5.80002C25.2 2.20002 30.2 7.90002 31.4 9.00002C31.7 8.00002 32 6.80002 32.2 5.80002C25.9 0.200024 19.3 1.10002 13.5 2.90002Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</svg>


<svg viewBox="0 0 31 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M12.8 2.20002C8.39999 3.70002 5.19999 3.60001 0.799988 1.30001C3.79999 14 14 24.5 14.5 25L15.5 26.1L16.6 25.1C17.1 24.6 26 16 30.2 5.10002C30.4 4.80002 24.5 -1.69998 12.8 2.20002ZM15.7 21.8C13.6 19.4 8.69999 13.4 5.69999 6.20002C7.79999 6.40002 10.4 6.20002 13.8 5.20002C20.8 3.20002 24.4 4.70002 26.6 6.10002C23.2 13.4 17.9 19.4 15.7 21.8Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</svg>
```

Я бы хотел собрать в один svg, я взял их из Figma. У меня там можно было только экспортировать 3 слоя по отдельности (вроде как)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: руками - javascript'том - gulp - webpack

Comment: @MaximLensky а как руками?

Comment: а вообще надо как то склеить слои в Figma при экспорте

Comment: @MaximLensky ок, спасибо

Comment: когда viewbox разные - сложнее, а так можно было бы сложить руками все одну svg и все

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я тупо сложил все viewBox и всё хотя на js это можно сделать

Comment: проверил в FF отлично работает - так же как и в Хром

Comment: На фигме положите 3 слоя этих в некую типа папку (group) и потом по папки (group) нажмите экспорт svg и все. Пример как по нормальному должно быть http://joxi.ru/E2pXeK8HaDZB92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для объединения трех SVG с разными `viewBox` можно воспользоваться командой `symbol`,
 которая имеет свой `viewBox`. То есть в одном svg будут три `symbol` с разными `viewBox`

Так как все, что находится внутри `symbol` невидимо, то вызываем содержимое с помощью `<use>`

```html
<style>
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
}
</style>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  style="border:0px solid;">
<symbol id="s1" viewBox="0 0 33 18" >
<path d="M16.6 0C16.5 0 16.4 0 16.3 0C8.50002 0 1.90002 5.5 0.400024 12.8C2.60002 14.1 6.20002 17.2 15 14.6C19.4 13.3 25 11.6 32.4 17.6C32.4 17.3 32.4 17 32.4 16.6C32.7 7.6 25.5 0.2 16.6 0ZM14.1 11.7C8.40003 13.4 5.40002 12.4 3.90002 11.5C5.90002 6.5 10.7 3 16.2 3H16.5C22.1 3.1 26.9 6.8 28.7 11.8C24 9.5 19.5 10 14.1 11.7Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</symbol>

<symbol id="s2" viewBox="0 0 33 9"  >
<path d="M13.5 2.90002C8.9 4.30002 4.7 3.90002 0 0.900024C0 2.00002 0.1 3.60003 0.2 4.60003C2.6 6.50003 8.3 7.80002 14.4 5.80002C25.2 2.20002 30.2 7.90002 31.4 9.00002C31.7 8.00002 32 6.80002 32.2 5.80002C25.9 0.200024 19.3 1.10002 13.5 2.90002Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</symbol>


<symbol id="s3" viewBox="0 0 31 27" >
<path d="M12.8 2.20002C8.39999 3.70002 5.19999 3.60001 0.799988 1.30001C3.79999 14 14 24.5 14.5 25L15.5 26.1L16.6 25.1C17.1 24.6 26 16 30.2 5.10002C30.4 4.80002 24.5 -1.69998 12.8 2.20002ZM15.7 21.8C13.6 19.4 8.69999 13.4 5.69999 6.20002C7.79999 6.40002 10.4 6.20002 13.8 5.20002C20.8 3.20002 24.4 4.70002 26.6 6.10002C23.2 13.4 17.9 19.4 15.7 21.8Z" fill="#5AA5DC"/>
</symbol> 
<use xlink:href="#s1" transform="translate(0, -21)" />
 <use xlink:href="#s2" transform="translate(0, -6)" />
  <use xlink:href="#s3" transform="translate(0, 19)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть также хорошее решение -> [vectr.com](https://vectr.com/)
**UPD:** или идётё в Google, пишите `svg редактор онлайн` и находите нужные ссылки

Comment: это опять какие то сервисы ..не то

Answer (score 1):

можно эти три svg в figma объединить в группу и потом скопировать svg